# Meteor and Ionic css not applied

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework

I would like to use the [meteoric](https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic) package to create a very simple app with meteor and the ionic framework. Using the [guide](https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic/blob/master/GUIDE.md), I created the following very simple app:

Router.js:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('MyTemplate');
});
```

Templates.html:

```
<template name="layout">
    {{#ionBody}}
        {{> ionNavBar}}

        {{#ionNavView}}
            {{> yield}}
        {{/ionNavView}}

    {{/ionBody}}
</template>

<template name="myTemplate">
    {{#ionContent}}
        Hello World!
    {{/ionContent}}
</template>
```

The app loads without errors, and shows the content "Hello World!" without any styling at all. For example, why is the iosNavBar not being shown?

Comment: I'm assuming you manually added the ionic-sass package, as well as fourseven:scss, yes?

Comment: also, when you inspect the dom, does the nav-bar div show up?

Comment: @Ramsay Lanier: Yes, I added the following packages as written in the meteoric guide: iron:router
fourseven:scss
meteoric:ionic-sass
meteoric:ionicons-sass
meteoric:ionic

Comment: Yes, the div is there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the installation instructions for ionic-sass:
https://github.com/meteoric/ionic-sass

It says:

> in your app's .scss file:
>
> @import
>   '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionic-sass/ionic';

So in your meteor application, create a style.scss file with the above import statement.  Now you should see the styles applied correctly.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick! Should definitely be included to the meteoric GUIDE

Answer (score 2):

for those who still find the icons missing  add the second line to import ionicons

@import '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionic-sass/ionic';

@import '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionicons-sass/ionicons';

sample app referrence link
https://github.com/meteoric/contacts/blob/master/client/stylesheets/app.scss

Comment: also if you are coding the routes and templates manually .... for people starting with meteor i would highly recommend using orion-cli as it creates the basic app structure, generates the routes and views for you with a couple of strokes . referrence https://github.com/matteodem/orion-cli